# Bootstrap VueJS Form select add Group Label

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, select, bootstrap-vue

I have a concatenated two arrays and it shows on the "*:options-"ObjOptions"*". How to add "*group labels*" to respective existing arrays using this bootstrap VueJS?

```
Sample, dropdown options should look like this:

--Apple //group label
----apple1
----apple2
----apple3
----apple4

--Banana //group label
----banana1
----banana2
----banana3
----banana4
```

```
<b-form-group>
  <b-form-select id="backdrop-variant" v-model="selected :options="ObjOptions"></b-form-select>
</b-form-group>
export default {

  data() {
      return {
      selected: null,
      ObjOptions:'',
      Array1: ["apple1","apple2","apple3"],
      Array2: ["banana1","banana2","banana3","banana4"],
      };
  },
  created: function (){
      let arr1 = this.Array1;
      let arr2 = this.Array2;
      this.ObjOptions = arr1.concat(arr2);
  },
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Groups can be created by using an object in the `options` array.

This object needs to include a `label` property which will be displayed above the group, and a `options` property which will be each element in the group.

In the snippet below I've used a computed property instead of setting the array in the `created` hook, since it will be more reactive in case your `Array1` or `Array2` arrays change.

You can of course still use the `created` hook if you feel like it better fits your application.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      selected: null,
      Array1: ["apple1", "apple2", "apple3"],
      Array2: ["banana1", "banana2", "banana3", "banana4"]
    };
  },
  computed: {
    ObjOptions() {
      const { Array1, Array2 } = this;

      return [
        {
          label: 'Apple',
          options: Array1
        },
        {
          label: 'Banana',
          options: Array2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.16.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.16.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-select v-model="selected" :options="ObjOptions"></b-select>
</div>
```